# Mysql Date/Datetime columns and Java persistence

Tags: java, mysql, persistence

I have a Mysql table with DATE column , default '0000-00-00'. If I try to call, for instance,
`em.find(MyTable.class,pk_value);`
 and it happens to be a record in database with default date value '0000-00-00', an exception is thrown(
"java.sql.SQLException: Value ... cannot be represented as java.sql.Date". The same error happens for DateTime columns with default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
Is it any way to tell EntityManager that such values are ok ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What helps is setting JDBC driver's zeroDateTimeBehavior property to convertToNull.

See http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/java/index.texy
(look for "SQLException for zero DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column? Use zeroDateTimeBehavior").

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

Answer (score 1):

By setting the `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` property we can avoid this problem. For details please check [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the ZERO dates to null.

Comment: I'm sure it will work, but it may cause many side effects, so I'd rather not do it unless it is the only solution.